# How to display a model state error in case I am returning a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following action method for creating new network info:-

```
public ActionResult CreateVMNetwork(int vmid)
        {
VMAssignIps vmips = new VMAssignIps()
{
TechnologyIP = new TechnologyIP() { TechnologyID = vmid},
IsTMSIPUnique = true,
IsTMSMACUnique = true
};
            return PartialView("_CreateVMNetwork",vmips);
}


 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateVMNetwork(VMAssignIps vmip)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                repository.InsertOrUpdateVMIPs(vmip.TechnologyIP,User.Identity.Name);
                repository.Save();
            return PartialView("_networkrow",vmip);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occurred: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

    }
    return PartialView("_CreateVMNetwork", vmip);

}
```

And I have the following _CreateVMNetwork view:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.VMAssignIps
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateVMNetwork", "VirtualMachine", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "networktable",
    LoadingElementId = "loadingimag",
    HttpMethod= "POST"
}))
{
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.TechnologyIP.TechnologyID)
    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEditVMNetwork", Model)

       <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
```

and _CreateOrEditVMNetwork view:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.VMAssignIps

<div>
<span class="f">IP Address</span> 

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.IPAddress)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.IPAddress)                                              

   <input type="CheckBox" name="IsTMSIPUnique" value="true" @(Html.Raw(Model.IsTMSMACUnique ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> | 
 <span class="f"> MAC Address</span>       
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.MACAddress)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.MACAddress)                                              

 <input type="CheckBox" name="IsTMSMACUnique" value="true" @(Html.Raw(Model.IsTMSMACUnique ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />

</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that in case there is a model state error when adding a new entity, a partial view will be displayed with the model state error as follow:-
[image]

So my question is , if there is a way to display the model state error with the partial view , without updating the table row “insert after” as I am doing currently?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the age i'm guessing you have already found a solution to this,

But here is an example using InsertionMode.Replace, maybe it can help someone else.

Snipped from view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddPerson", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "UpdateSection" }))
{

    <div id="UpdateSection">

        @Html.Partial("PersonModel", Model.Person)

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="add" />
}
```

Snipped from the controller

```
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        return PartialView("AddPerson", Person);
    }
```

just make sure the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" script is included (i'm not sure it is by default)